# Ignore required form fields if bootstrap 5 accordion is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

**I would like to ignore the required fields of a form if the accordion in which that field is located is collapsed/closed.**

E.G: If I have three accordions and each accordion has an input, the first accordion has to meet the requirement of `required` no matter what, but the other accordions if at the moment of submitting the form they are collapsed, those fields declared as required must be ignored and the form must be able to be sent normally to the backend.

**Use case**:

*Accordion 1*: Open. Input 1 (required) has a value.

*Accordion 2*: Closed. Input 2 (required) has a value too.

*Accordion 3*: Closed. Input 3 (required) does not have a value.

**Expected behavior**:

Form will submit the values of `Input 1` and `Input 2` and will ignore `Input 3` (even it's declared as a required field) or just assign a value to `Input 3` like `'None'`.

I have tried to find similar questions but since accordions are a new feature in bootstrap 5 I could not find anything similar.

What would be the most recommended way of doing it?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 1
        <input type="text" name="input_1" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 1" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 2
        <input type="text" name="input_2" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 2" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 3
        <input type="text" name="input_3" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 3" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a click handler in Javascript that would look for all elements that match the selector `.accordion-collapse.collapse:not(.show) input` and remove the `required` attribute from them.

```js
function handleSubmit() {
  // Make all input fields "required":
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse.collapse input');
  elements.forEach(function(e){
    e.required = true;
  });
    
  // Un-require the hidden input fields:
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-collapse.collapse:not(.show) input');
  elements.forEach(function(e){
    e.required = false;
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form onclick="handleSubmit();">
<div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 1
        <input type="text" name="input_1" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 1" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 2
        <input type="text" name="input_2" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 2" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingThree">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        Input 3
        <input type="text" name="input_3" class="form-control" aria-label="Input 3" required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It looks very clean, however I have some questions:

1. Why we need to make all input fields `required`? The `required` input fields are already marked as `required` in the html part. The code I posted here is an example, in each accordion there will be N inputs, some will be required and others will not. If all of them are `required`, inputs that are not required will be  required and that's not what I need.
2. Maybe I did not explain myself well but the first accordion (whether it is closed or open) has to meet the `required` requirement, it can not be empty.

Comment: @Cheknov Consider this situation: Item 1 is the only accordion item that is currently open. The user leaves the Input 1 blank and tries to submit the form. If the script were to change Input 2 and Input 3 to unrequired, the browser would then stop the form from being submitted because Item 1 is still required. So far so good. But now the inputs in Item 2 and Item 3 are now *not* required. So if the user closes Item 1 and opens Item 2, they can then leave Input 2 blank and submit the form and it will get submitted. That is why all inputs must be made required before un-requiring others.

Comment: @Cheknov If Item 1 should always be required regardless of whether it is open, you can change the selectors to ignore the first item: change `.accordion-item:not(:first-child) .accordion-collapse.collapse input` to `.accordion-collapse.collapse input` and change `.accordion-collapse.collapse:not(.show) input` to `accordion-item:not(:first-child) .accordion-collapse.collapse:not(.show) input`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I upvoted and accepted your answer